# how add custom javascript file in UI_component?

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent

I have a layout:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
> <update handle="editor"/>
> <body>
>     <referenceContainer name="content">
>         <uiComponent name="name_name2_form"/>
>     </referenceContainer>
> </body> </page>
> ```

and want to add custom JS file, so that it only works here (this UI component)
How I can do this? Ty for answer

Answer (score -1):

> you can try this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <!-- Add local resources -->
    <css src="css/my-styles.css"/>

    <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
    <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
    <link src="js/sample.js"/>

    <!-- Add external resources -->
<css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
    <link src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" /> 
</head>
```